# How to properly migrate Node.js project

Tags: node.js, api, rest

We have a big Nodejs project that we feel cannot scale any more. This is due to rushed decisions to come up with new models, attributes, and and request handlers just to respond to client need.

Now, we came to a point where the code structure is slowing us down. That's when we decided to refactor the existing code. The problem is that we have two separate client sides working on prod with real people data.

I've been asked to come up with a plan for this migration from the old code structure to a new more scalable one without, of course, affecting the client side.

Here is what I thought about:

- Create a new branch called v2 and start everything over **(easy, simple, yet slow)**
- Stay on the same branch, create a new folder called v2, and create the new modules there one by one. Then, update the frontend with new calls.
- Stay on the same branch, use the same code, yet create a new folder under `routes` for the new endpoints and add new methods to the controller and services.

I feel very lost in this. I don't know if the things I thought about can be useful.

How do people move from one version to another without affecting the prod?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer is late,
I think you want to make your project scalable by sticking to the same behaviors, and remember that the same behaviors will lead to the same results.

your project reached the level that your code cannot be scaled anymore and this may be because bad decisions are taken so plz don't repeat this, or maybe your project is not scalable because of performance issues.

if your problems are related to code organization, you need to find another way of thinking.

As I see what you have currently is a three-layered architecture which has some limitations regarding to code scaling

instead of that you could have something like 4 layered architecture which will help you more to define your business logic in a more clean way and encapsulate it inside a domain layer

this architecture code is one of the following:

- clean architecture
- onion architecture
- hexagonal architecture

You can learn more about these architectures, the clean architecture is well explained by Oncle Bon [here](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html)

You can also think about Domain Driven Design, which will help you more to think about your domain problems and define your domain boundaries in a good way